# How can I use EMUI 9's twin-app feature witg any app on a non-rooted device?

Tags: emui

I'd like to clone a few apps on my phone (honor Play) without root or any 3rd party app. I've followed [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-clone-any-application-with-emuis-app-twin-feature-no-root/) article but the cloned apps don't show up on the phone.
Is there a way to use this feature with anything else other than facebook and Whatsapp without root/3rd party apps?